# Cron Job Cluster environment

Tags: cron

I need to know how we can setup cron jobs in cluster environment.
I have 4+1 cluster environment , first server is running crontab scripts and in case it gets down cron should be shifted to another. How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

One common resource is [rcron](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Frcron%2F&ei=cjosVLoLxq2iBPnDgcgI&usg=AFQjCNFPU4xory3vlhJSEpJo0YRDSYenkw&sig2=5v03ilockLOMTTzvTprOcg).  This project hasn't been updated in a while, but still compiles fine.  It works by using a state file to determine if it is the active server.  Rcron doesn't update the state file itself, however; it relies on a service like [Heartbeat](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) to update the state file for you.  It works by having you prepend each cron command in your regular cron with rcron, i.e.:

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/myscript.sh 2>/dev/null
```

Would become

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/rcron /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/myscript.sh 2>/dev/null
```

As you can see, you could *also* just implement your own script that performs this kind of function:

```
0 * * * * /usr/local/scripts/active_or_not.sh && /bin/bash /usr/local/scripts/myscript.sh 2>/dev/null
```

Where the contents of the script is something like:

```
#! /bin/bash
shouldIBeActive() {
    # See if this server is able to run all the crons correctly
    canRun || return 1
    # See if there is already another server set to active
    shouldRun || return 1 # Maybe even still using Hearbeat for a state file
}

if [ shouldIBeActive ]; then
    logger "Set to active server"
    exit 0
else
    logger "Not set to be active."
    exit 1
fi
```

If you want to avoid having to updated this cron on multiple servers, you could use NFS or DRBD or something to have a shared crontab, although its reliability will suddenly become dependent on that.