# How can I ensure cron job runs only on one host at any time

Tags: python, database, cron, distributed

I have a django management command run as a cron job and it is set on multiple hosts to run at the same time. What is the best way to ensure that cron job runs on only one host at any time? One approach is to use db locks as the cron job updates a MySQL db but I am sure there are better(django or pythonic) approaches to achieve what I am looking for

Comment: One way would be to use a version of cron with clustering support and share /var/spool/cron over all hosts in the cron cluster. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html#CLUSTERING_SUPPORT and http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/crontab.1.html for more info.  If the cron job does not have run often, a cronjob could be separately configured to run at staggered times on the hosts.

Comment: @TrisNefzger: can your solution be used for hosts across different clusters?

Comment: Yes, provided the same /var/spool/cron can be shared on all hosts since that's what makes them a cron cluster.  It may be simpler to start cron jobs from a single host that runs them remotely using ssh. Cronlock is a another tool for cron syncronization across hosts using redis, see https://github.com/kvz/cronlock.  Also Google developed rcron in 2009 for the same purpose, see  https://code.google.com/p/rcron/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23153379/cron-job-cluster-environment for more about it.

Answer (score -1):

simple way: 
 - start cron before need time (for example two minutes)
 - force synchronize time (using ntp or ntpdate) (optional paranoid mode)
 - wait till expected time, run job